# If $\zeta(s)=0$ with $\Re(s)=\frac{1}{2}$, is then $|\hat{\zeta}(s,3)|^2=\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, dirichlet-series

Helmut Hasse has proved that for $s \in \mathbb{C}-\{1\}$ the Riemann zeta function can be written as:

$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\ {n \choose k}\ \frac{1}{(k+1)^{s}}$$

Let $K(a,b) = \frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}$. Then we might define:

$$\hat{\zeta}(s,a)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\ {n \choose k} K(k,a)^{s}$$

Then $\hat{\zeta}(s,1) = \zeta(s)$.

I looked at some non-trivial zeros of $\zeta$ and computed numerically in SAGEMATH:

**If $\zeta(s)=0$ with $\Re(s)=\frac{1}{2}$, is then $|\hat{\zeta}(s,3)|^2=\frac{1}{2}$ or is this just some bug / numerical curiosity in my code?**

Here is the SAGE Code:

```
def K(a,b):
    return gcd(a,b)/(a+b)

def zzeta(s,a=1,N=400):
        return 1/(1-2**(1-s))*sum([ 1/2**(n+1)*sum([ (-1)**k*binomial(n,k)*K(k,a)**s for k in range(n+1)]) for n in range(0,N+1)])


zz = zeta_zeros()

for z in zz[0:100]:
    print( abs(zzeta(1/2+z*I,3))**2)
```

And here is some of the ouptut:

```
0.5000000001016516
0.49999999980871757
0.49999999990048116
0.4999999999150287
0.5000000001425052
0.5000000003259728
0.4999999999688171
0.5000000000737418
0.5000000004006991
0.5000000003452242
0.49999999982210547
0.5000000000784613
0.49999999939079287
0.5000000012082603
0.5000000000591772
0.5000000002545129
0.4999999996870637
```

Some data for $a=2$:

```
0.5027599264329976
0.4120370789607451
0.3869873346989051
0.2811880366841188
0.2594539123560252
0.7742279955909737
0.18310290214474273
0.4006464279725155
0.2723910071065707
0.16780149194046892
```

Comment: This looks like some kind of "inner Fourier transform" of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN why fourier transform?

Comment: I find the same 0.5 with Mathematica, so it does not seem to be a bug.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker thanks for verifying this with mathematica

Comment: Have you also computed $\vert\hat{\zeta}(s,k)\vert^{2}$ for other integral values of $k$ like $k=2$ ou $k=4$? I expect a cyclic phenomenon of order $4$ to be involved.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Yes but I could not see any pattern.

Comment: Can you share these data?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: Yes, just a minute, I have to recompute for $a=2$.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN I updated the question with some data for $a=2$.

Comment: I get a similar result with Mathematica so I don't think there's a bug in your code. I plotted $|\hat{\zeta}(s,3)|$ along the critical line and it seems to be a minimum at or near the non-trivial zeta zeros.

Comment: @StevenClark can you share your plot?

Comment: Tried it in Maple and obtain the same results as well. Note that when you feed $|\hat{\zeta}(s,3)|^2$ with the trivial zeta zeros $s=-2,-4,-6$, you get the results $\frac{9}{49},  \frac{225}{961},\frac{3969}{16129$}$ which follow a simple formula.

Comment: @Agno thats cool. I will try this.

Comment: @orgesleka, I believe it is: $\left( \frac{2^{-s}-1}{2^{1-s}-1} \right)^2$ for $s=-2,-4,-6...$.

Comment: @Agno: Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is just a simple calculation.  Note that 
$$
\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \binom{n}{k} =1 
$$ 
for any non-negative integer $k$, which immediately gives 
$$ 
\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^s} \binom{n}{k} = \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 
\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^s}  = \zeta(s).
$$

Similarly, 
$$ 
{\hat \zeta}(s,3) = \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k K(k,3)^s = \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k (k,3)^s}{(k+3)^s}. 
$$
Separating out terms with $3|k$, we may rewrite the sum over $k$ above as 
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+3)^s} + (3^s-1)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{3k}}{(3k+3)^s}\\
 = &-1 + \frac{1}{2^s} +\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^s} + \frac{3^s-1}{3^s} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^s}.
\end{align*} 
Therefore 
$$
{\hat \zeta}(s,3) = \frac{-1+2^{-s}}{1-2^{1-s}} + \zeta(s) + \frac{3^s-1}{3^s} \zeta(s).
$$
Now evaluate this at a zero of $\zeta(s)$ on the critical line (or anywhere else).

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: OK so values of $\hat\zeta(s,3)$ at zeroes of $\zeta(s)$ on the critical line lie on the circle with radius $\sqrt2$. However it turns out they are by no means uniformly distributed on that circle. Rather, these values seem to tend accumulating near $-\sqrt2$: mean of the real parts of the first 100 of them is around $-0.6$ (standard deviation about $0.18$). Can this also be explained?

Comment: @Lucia: Is it possible to extend your formula for arbitrary $a \in \mathbb{N}$? How would this look like?

Comment: @orgesleka, I believe that for $a=1$ or $a$ is an odd prime, the following is true:
$${\hat \zeta}(s,a)=\left(1-\frac{1}{a^s} \right) \zeta(s)+(-1)^a \, \dfrac{\zeta\left(s,\frac{a+1}{2} \right)-\zeta\left(s,\frac{a}{2}\right)}{2^s-2}$$ 
where $\zeta(s,x)$ is the Hurwitz zeta function.

Comment: @Agno: Did you verify this numerically or do you have a proof?

Comment: @orgesleka, I just followed Lucia's logic and separated out the terms with $p|$ ($p =$ odd prime). Then this formula follows. Also verified it numerically and found that it didn't work for $p=2$ (don't know why yet).

Comment: Perhaps a minor point with respect to this question, but note the originally formula for $\zeta(s)$ is globally convergent except for $s=1+\frac{2\,\pi\,i\,m}{\log(2)}$ for some integer m whereas the simplified formula for $\zeta(s)$ in the answer above has the additional constraint $\Re(s)>0$.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე: do you mean "of radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$"?

Comment: @orgesleka, for $a=2$ the closed form simply becomes: $|\hat{\zeta}(s,2)|=\dfrac{2^s+\zeta(s)}{2^s-2}$. I had overlooked in Lucia's post that $(-1)^{3k}=(-1)^k$ will for $a=2$ obviously become $(-1)^{2k}= 1$. So, we now have a closed form for all $a=$ prime and for $a=1$.

Comment: @Agno thanks for your effort

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Yes, sorry. Accordingly, $-\sqrt2$ should be $-\frac1{\sqrt2}$

Comment: Yes, around $-0.707106$...it would be interesting to relate the arguments of the critical zeros $s$ of zeta and the ones of values $\hat{\zeta}(s,3)$ to explain why the latter should accumulate near $\pi$.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN On the other hand it might be sort of red herring. Values of $\frac{-1+2^{-s}}{1-2^{1-s}}$ for $s=\frac12+it$ where $t$ is a random real uniformly distributed in, say, interval $(0,1000000)$, exhibit a similar distribution.

Comment: I don't understand your simplification step. The identity $\sum\limits_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\binom{n}{k}=1$ does not imply $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum_\limits{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^{s}}{n\choose k}=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum_\limits{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^s}\binom{n}{k}$, does it? The simplified formula is clearly not equivalent to the original formula since they have different domains of convergence.

Answer (score 5):

The intent of this post is to share some results as requested in the comments above and assumes the following definitions from the original question above.

---

**(1)** $\quad\zeta(s)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_\limits{n=0}^N\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum_\limits{k=0}^n(-1)^k\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 n \\
 k \\
\end{array}
\right)\frac{1}{(k+1)^s}\right)$

**(2)** $\quad\hat{\zeta}(s,a)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_\limits{n=0}^N\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum_\limits{k=0}^n(-1)^k\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 n \\
 k \\
\end{array}
\right)K(k,a)^{s}\right),\qquad K(a,b)=\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}$

---

The following figure illustrates formula (2) above for $|\hat{\zeta}(s,3)|$ plotted along the critical line $s=\frac{1}{2}+i\ t$. The red discrete portion of the plot represents the evaluation of formula (2) for $|\hat{\zeta}(s,3)|$ at the first 10 non-trivial zeta zeros in the upper half plane. In the plot in the figure below formula (2) was evaluated  using an upper limit of $N=400$.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (2) evaluated along the critical line]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (2) for $|\hat{\zeta}(s,3)|$ evaluated along the critical line

---

The following conjectured formulas based on my [Questions related to globally convergent formulas for the Dirichlet eta function $\eta(s)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3347821) seem to evaluate considerably faster than formulas (1) and (2) above and perhaps provide some additional insight.

---

**(3)** $\quad\zeta(s)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{\left(1-2^{1-s}\right)\ 2^{N+1}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^N (-1)^n\ \frac{1}{(n+1)^s}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-n} \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 N+1 \\
 N-n-k \\
\end{array}
\right)\right)$

**(4)** $\quad\hat{\zeta}(s,a)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{\left(1-2^{1-s}\right)\ 2^{N+1}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^N (-1)^n\ K(n,a)^{s}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-n} \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 N+1 \\
 N-n-k \\
\end{array}
\right)\right)$

---

The following figure illustrates formula (4) above for $|\hat{\zeta}(s,3)|$ plotted along the critical line $s=\frac{1}{2}+i\ t$. The red discrete portion of the plot represents the evaluation of formula (4) for $|\hat{\zeta}(s,3)|$ at the first 10 non-trivial zeta zeros in the upper half plane. In the plot in the figure below, formula (4) was evaluated using an upper limit of $N=400$.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (4)]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of formula (4) for $|\hat{\zeta}(s,3)|$ evaluated along the critical line

---

Formula (5) below is from the [accepted answer to this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/357582) posted by [Lucia](https://mathoverflow.net/users/38624/lucia).

**(5)** $\quad\hat{\zeta}(s,3)=\frac{2^{-s}-1}{1-2^{1-s}}+\zeta(s)+\frac{3^s-1}{3^s} \zeta(s)$

---

The following figure illustrates formula (5) above for $|\hat{\zeta}(s,3)|$ and $\left|\frac{2^{-s}-1}{1-2^{1-s}}\right|$ in blue and orange respectively where both functions are evaluated along the critical line $s=\frac{1}{2}+i\ t$. The red discrete portion of the plot represents the evaluation of formula (5) for $|\hat{\zeta}(s,3)|$ at the first 10 non-trivial zeta zeros in the upper half plane.

[image: Illustration of formula (5)]

**Figure (3)**: Illustration of formula (5) for $|\hat{\zeta}(s,3)|$ evaluated along the critical line

Comment: thanks for sharing your plot.